# Modular arithmatic $x^a \mod N= a\cdot b$

Tags: number-theory

$x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod{15}$

How to solve it mod $3$ and mod $5$?

And how does the Chinese remainder theorem help?

I want a general method to follow in case the modulus is composite number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use double dollar symbol to write $x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod{15}$. Just right click on my text and click see tex command to see how I did it!

Comment: Welcome btw! ^^ there are commands like \equiv to write triple lines end \modp{n} to write properly mod.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try to learn those commands !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^3\equiv 2\pmod{15}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}x^3\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\x^3\equiv 2\pmod{5}\end{cases}$

It is clear that if $x\equiv 0$ or $x\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ that $x^3\not\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ so we know that $x\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.  Checking confirms this since $2^3=8\equiv 2\pmod{3}$

For the second implication, it should be clear that $x\equiv 0,1,4\pmod{5}$ will result in $x^3\equiv 0,1,4\pmod{5}$ respectively.  We are left to check when $x\equiv 3$ and $2$.

$2^3=8\equiv 3\pmod{5}$

$3^3=27\equiv 2\pmod{5}$

Thus, we have the system of congruencies $\begin{cases}x\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\x\equiv 3\pmod{5}\end{cases}$

Applying chinese remainder theorem and solving the system yields $x\equiv 8\pmod{15}$